# How do I commit my changes on .git/hooks/pre-commit file

Tags: git

I'm using GitLab for this repo, and I've changed my pre-commit file from this:

```
if [ "$FILES" != "" ]
then
    echo "Running Code Sniffer..."
    ./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2 --encoding=utf-8 -n -p $FILES
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
    echo "Fix the error before commit."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

to this:

```
if [ "$FILES" != "" ]
then
    echo "Convert files from DOS to UNIX standart";
    php ./dos2unix.php $FILES
fi

if [ "$FILES" != "" ]
then
    echo "Running Code Sniffer..."
    ./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2 --encoding=utf-8 -n -p $FILES
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "Fix the error before commit."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

But every time I merge from another branch or create a new branch the new code disappears.

How do I commit this changes, so any new branch has the same pre-commit file?

Comment: Nothing in `.git/` can be committed so you probably have something in addition to `.git/hooks/pre-commit`; may be the file is actually is a symlink into repository?

Comment: @phd its not a link its the original file, but I don`t no how to persist the changes among all branches.

Comment: Does it disappear at all, so the file is empty? Or does it rollback to the previous pre-commit file code?
U can try to change permissions to that file (not to be executable), and wait where the commit fails.
It looks like some other hook modifies it.